# How to use one css file (external stylesheet) for multiple pages?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to coding. I want to create a portfolio site with different pages. So far I've created my landing page (index.html). Now I'd like to work on my about.html page (later my contact page, resume page, etc). I have to use the same CSS sheet for all my pages. To do so I linked the CSS to all of them. Now every time I edit the css on one page it changes all the others. I want some elements to be the same, but others different. For instance, I don't want my "about" page to have content that's going to be on my "contact" page.

Comment: "Now every time I edit the css on one page it changes all the others." — Isn't that the point?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Shared CSS is for general styling of your site and repeat elements, e.g. if each page has a header area or footer. For page-specific styles, use page-specific CSS files or at least target specific pages in your CSS rules. A simple way to do this is to ensure each page has an ID on its body tag; you can then target a page via a rule like `#page-about h1 { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. Say I want to have a contact box on my contact page. I want to keep some elements the same, such as my header, nav, font, etc. But I don't want the contact box to show up on every single page. I think adding IDs in the body of each page will work. I'll test it out

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you desire.

1. You create a CSS file for each page and just copy and paste the code from the CSS file that you used for the index page. Afterwards, edit the file to style the about page if you want it to look differently than the index page.
2. You import the index CSS file using @import handler into a new CSS file that will be used to style the about page and add code to the CSS file to customize the about page.

At the end of the day, the best way to style multiple pages is to create several CSS files. One file to contain common properties to all pages such as the font-size for elements if the font size will be the same on all pages. Additional CSS files to customize each page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a very simple, conventional and modular approach.

- Put all your CSS code that are globally used in your website into one and name it main.css.
- Create individual CSS files for each page and write code in it to add / override the styles. For example: about.css for About page.